# T_LNumber PHP error

Tags: php, meta-tags, meta

I am reviewing a website that was designed years ago. There is a problem on the contact page 
that spits an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in /home/content/p/r/e/prentexaf1/html/contact.php on line 61

Line 61 is that which starts: print"meta...

Here is the entire function around it:

```
function redirectTo($to) {

    $url = $to;

    print "<html><head><script>    location.href='$url'¥n  </script>";
    print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=¥"0; URL=$url¥">";
    print "</head><body>If you see this page, click <a href=¥"$url¥">here</a> to continue</body>";
    print "</html>";
    exit;
}
```

I'm unfamiliar with php enough not to know what problem is happening here (I did not write this function, just am trying to solve the error for a friend that owns the site [also didn't write it]). I've looked up the meta tag info. My instincts says this is an issue following content but that's just a hunch. Please advise.. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are these doing in there `¥` it looks like one of the characters in the Space Invaders video game lol. Those shouldn't be there, remove them.

Comment: The syntax highlighter shows your error

Comment: So these Y have no place in here where they are crossed out by the post issue? Sorry to have bothered you then.

Comment: Hm? Removing the Ys that are apparently not normal did not change the issue; still getting same error.

Comment: Besides those, I can't see how it could go wrong. How are you using the function? Maybe that small `n` in `'$url'¥n` has something to do with it.

Comment: You'll want to escape the `"`s also.  So `print "...<a href=\"$url\">...";`

Comment: It's the default in a switch case.. apparently posting the entire default is too many characters; I'll try in a separate comment
 
@Fred-ii-

Comment: I fixed your code. Consult my answer below. @user3614489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the double quotes needed to be escaped. (Besides the funky `¥` characters which have been removed)

```
function redirectTo($to) {

    $url = $to;

print "<html><head><script>location.href='$url'</script>";
print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=\"0; URL=$url\">";
print "</head><body>If you see this page, click <a href=\"$url\">here</a> to continue</body>";
print "</html>";
exit;
}
```

they (quotes) might have been accidently replaced with that character, using a Word processor of sorts.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That makes so much sense... (though who knows how long ago that happened and who in the series of people fiddling with this site did it...) Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You're quite welcome, happy to have helped. @user3614489

Comment: @user3614489 Please reload my answer. I realized I made a slight mistake (*nothing major*). Re-copy the code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay! Thank you. I have one additional question though; I noticed that the same syntax issue with the Y vs the / were in the function to check the contact form entries; Now however it's not checking the entries at all... (I'll post a comment with only the function)

Comment: function checkf(f) {

    if(!f.pName.value.match(//w/)) {
   f.pName.focus();
   alert('Please enter Your Name');
   return false;
  }
    if(!f.pEmail.value.match(//w@/w/)) {
   f.pEmail.focus();
   alert('Please enter Your Email');
   return false;
  }
  if(f.recip.selectedIndex <1) {
   f.recip.focus();
   alert("Please select request recipient");
   return false;
  }
  f.todo.value= 'save';
  return true;
 }

Comment: Hi @user3614489 I couldn't come up with a solution for it, sorry.